# Why GraphQL and Strapi isn't working on AWS ECS?

Tags: graphql, amazon-ecs, strapi, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have a Strapi App (v4) running as a Docker image on AWS Fargate,
everything worked perfectly untill I decided to install GraphQL and pushed the updated image to the ECR.
Once the task starts running I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ApplicationError is not a constructor
   at /strapi-api/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-graphql/server/services/builders/dynamic-zones.js:17:15 ...
```

the weired thing is that when I run the docker-image locally I get no errors at all and GraphQL is working properly.

hope someone could help me with this error,
thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure you are running the exact same docker image locally as on ECS? I wouldn't expect this type of error to occur only on AWS.

Comment: 150% sure, tried to run it like a hundred times.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I've had a problem with my components folder that is connected to the AWS EFS, I created the project from scratch and now it works like a charm.
So if you're having this kind of problem, try creating a new strapi app.

For reference:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12547Tg

:)